# How to remove 1 line of CSS in theme

Tags: css, wordpress, header, themes

I have a theme which has a cloned header (and provides absolutely zero way to customise it). When the cloned header appears on scroll, it is aligned left.

Looking at google console, it reveals this flex container:

```
div.whb-flex-flex-middle .whb-col-center {
    flex: 1 1 0%
```

If I delete this in the theme's code, it works as I'd like. But updating the theme refreshes the edit. I have installed a child theme, but wondering how I'd go about removing this without having to re-do it every time I update. I'm using WordPress.

Is there any CSS code that would solve this.

Deleted code in header-base-min.css - works as expected, but theme resets edit upon update.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what the problem is as you are using a child theme. This won't get overwritten when the parent theme is updated so your alteration (which must not be to the parent's style file but to the child's) will remain. Can  you expand a bit on exactly where you are making the alteration?

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the confusion… I did the edits in the parent / main theme, but after I updated it and obviously the css got refreshed, that’s when I installed the child theme. The child then references the code of the parent so I’m unsure exactly what to put in the child theme to remove the line of css. Sorry for these incredibly basic questions.

Comment: By "Google console", do you mean the dev tools in Chrome?

Comment: Indeed. I inspected the element to find the CSS

Comment: Read up about how to install a child theme especially how to have additions to the style.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the CSS document of the theme by making a copy or just copy/pasting the CSS into a new document. then, make whatever changes you want and use your new and (hopefully) improved CSS as the website theme.

If this doesn't work, then maybe you could download one of those extensions that lets you write custom themes for websites (I use stylus) and write some simple CSS declaring whatever you don't like to have 0 width, or a similar approach.

I'm assuming you don't need perfectly clean code- if you do, then it might be best to just write your own website theme. I've done it before and it's really fun. Take an afternoon to make a site look goofy. This is your sign.